# Remove duplicate data in a rows from data frame python without affecting the shape of the DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

have a data-frame :

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
> ==> index   A  B
>       0     1  10
>       1     1  20
>       2     1  30 
>       3     2  10
```

I want to remove duplicates from column A but the shape of the data Frame not to be affected.

Resultant O/p to be

```html
> ==> Index  A  B
>       0       10
>       1    1  20
>       2       30
>       3    2  10
```

How to complete this task.

Comment: What's the logic of keeping row `1` and removing rows `0` and `2`?

Comment: Its not removing row 0 and 2, Any row can be retained. But row 0,1,2 had value 1 and final out put should have removed the duplicated value without removing any rows. So rows 0,1,2 will represent the value 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follows, you can select the duplicated rows and column of interest ('A') and set the value to NAN.

```py
# create df

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 10],
    [1, 20],
    [1, 30],
    [2, 10]],
    columns=['A', 'B'])

# replace duplicated elements with NAN, preserving the row

df.loc[df.duplicated(subset='A', keep='first'), 'A'] = np.nan
```

Original Table:

```
    A   B
0   1   10
1   1   20
2   1   30
3   2   10
```

Modified Table:

```
    A     B
0   1.0   10
1   NaN   20
2   NaN   30
3   2.0   10
```

Column 'A' becomes a floating point datatype to support NaN.

Using `duplicated` you can specify the first (`keep='first'`) or last (`keep='last'`) occurrence of the element as the original – as it were – where the other same elements are considered the duplicates.

Related to @Quang Hoang's comment, there is no logic in `duplicated` to select an arbitrary middle element, as in your example.

*************************** Following Response ***************************

Following your response, I think I understand what you want. The following is non-vectorised approach that should be fine as long as your dataframe isn't huge. It saves duplicate B values into a list (see below)

```py
# create sample dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 10],
    [1, 20],
    [1, 30],
    [2, 10],
    [3, 15],
    [3, 20]],
    columns=['A', 'B'])

# create a dictionary where unique column A values are keys, and values are all the column B values for a given key (whether the A value is a duplicate or not)

dictionary = dict()

for value in df.A.unique():
    if len(df.loc[(df.A == value) & df.A.duplicated(keep=False)]) > 0:
        all_values = df.loc[(df.A == value) & df.A.duplicated(keep=False), 'B'].tolist()
        dictionary[value] = all_values
    elif len(df.loc[(df.A == value) & df.A.duplicated(keep=False)]) == 0:
        dictionary[value] = df.loc[(df.A == value), 'B'].tolist()

# make a new dataframe

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])
df2.A = list(dictionary.keys())
df2.B = list(dictionary.values())
```

The result is this:

```
    A    B
0   1   [10, 20, 30]
1   2   [10]
2   3   [15, 20]
```

If you wish to delete the original dataframe to release memory: `del df`

Comment: Partially this works. Thanks for the effort @David1592.
1.Column A value 1 represents Value 10,20 and 30 which is on Column B. If column A is replace with NAN values; Column A value 1 represents Value 10 which is on Column B and Value 20,30 is kindly of loss.